# Notification icon showing blank on android 13

Tags: android, android-13

The notification icons on Android 13 are blank.

Check below screenshot-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thats because it have solid background. implement [adaptive icon](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive), split background (shape) and foreground (icon) layers. for Android 13 you may even customize it a bit more:

> Starting with Android 13 (API level 33), you can opt-in to providing a
>  drawable.

`<monochrome android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_monochrome" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option even you are using minimum android SDK version 19 or 33.This solution will work.
Don't Waste your Time on minimum SDK version 21 to 26:
Android 13 uses a plain icon with the background color.
Just follow these simple steps:

- Just Export Your Logo in Transparent SVG format.
- Transparent means only the logo identity part without a background.
- Import this logo in the android @drawable folder as vector SVG.
- In the Notification Channel that you are using to make status
  notifications!

  ```
   val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "FIRE_BASE_NOTIFICATION")
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.transparent_logo)
   .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_primary2))
   .setContentTitle(title)
   .setContentText(message)
   .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
   .setVibrate(LongArray(0))

   NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(1, builder. Build())
  ```

In Android 11+ even if you add a fill-color logo it will automatically convert it into a single plain color, If you do not set the background color then it will show a grey-filled circle. That will hide your logo identity.
Thanks
Get rid of this problem as adaptive icons were introduced in Android 8.0 (API level 26)